# How to edit HTML of WOOCOMMERCE product cateogory page?

Tags: wordpress

I can change the html to the desired effect using Google Chrome, however when I use a FTP or file manager, I can't do the same in the php files.

Please Help.

Comment: You have to override html WooCommerce  template files to your theme.

Answer (score 1):

Here to find archive product html

**Theme Folder Path :** yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php

### **OR**

**Plugin Folder Path :** plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that via FTP because the pages are stored in the database.

Use the following approach:

1. Go to your Wordpress dashboard
2. Navigate to Dashboard -> Appearance -> Editor
   [image: Navigation]
3. From there you can edit/modify your HTML of WooCommerce
   [image: Editing]